# how to use .cshtml and other file types as a string in C# for building developer documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, documentation

How can I render out files like `.cshtml`, `.scss`, `.ts`, etc. in `C#`/ `Razor` to be used for documentation?

For clarity, I'm looking for something like the following:

```
<section>
   <pre>
      @SomeWayToShow("~/path/to/accordian-tabs.cshtml")
   </pre>
   <pre>
      @SomeWayToShow("~/path/to/_accordian-tabs.scss")
   </pre>
   <pre>
      @SomeWayToShow("~/path/to/accordian-tabs.ts")
   </pre>
</section>
```

Here is an example from bourbon.io as an example of the end goal.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the [`function`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/timlee/2010/07/30/using-functions-in-an-asp-net-page-with-razor-syntax/) block, for sample:

```
@functions {

   string SomeWayToShow(string path)
   {
       var filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);

       if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
          return System.IO.File.ReadlAllText(filePath);

       return string.Empty;
   }

}
```

If can help you to provide the content of a given file in `path` argument. To format it, you should take a look at some components to highlight the result.